# How to get the Utilized storage of the AWS RDS instance using python

Tags: python

I am trying to get the utilized storage of the AWS RDS instance using python scripts.

I have used the python boto3 for getting AWS RDS freestoragespace matrics in gigabytes but it is not giving me expected output.,your help is much required.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.